# Getting error when I run Strapi in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, strapi

I am running Strapi in a Kubernetes cluster containing a postgres deployment with persistent volume (cluster ip) | strapi deployment (cluster ip) | nginx ingress

I am able to connect to my Strapi deployment using `IP/admin` and I get the Strapi registration screen and register, but when I try to login I get and error message saying "**Error: an error occurred**" with no other lead, the progress indicator just keeps spinning forever, even when check the Strapi pod logs there is no *404* error or anything like that, all http statuses are *200*, but for some reason I am still getting the error despite trying everything, below you'll find my Ingreres/Postgres/Strapi configuration

**PS: the same configuration is working locally using NodePort**

**Ingress**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: 'nginx'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /admin
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: strapi-cluster-ip-service
              port:
                number: 1337
```

**Postgres**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
       labels:
         component: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: database-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: strapi
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: strapi
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: <PASSWORD>
```

**Strapi**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: strapi-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: strapi
  template:
    metadata:
       labels:
         component: strapi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: strapi
          image: alexyib/strapi-generic:v1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1337
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_CLIENT
              value: postgres
            - name: DATABASE_NAME
              value: strapi
            - name: DATABASE_HOST
              value: postgres-cluster-ip-service
            - name: DATABASE_PORT
              value: '5432'
            - name: DATABASE_USERNAME
              value: strapi
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              value: <PASSWORD>
```

**alexyib/strapi-generic:v1** was created using the below Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14

ENV APP_HOME /usr/src/app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD ./package.json .
ADD ./yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

ADD . .

ENV NODE_ENV production
RUN yarn install

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Any advise? Thank you in advance,
I will gladly provide any other configuration files needed but didn't want this topic to become very long

---

> **System Information**
>
> - **Strapi Version**: 4.1.2
> - **Operating System**: Kubernetes Cluster
> - **Database**: postgres
> - **Node Version**: 14.19.0
> - **Yarn Version**: 1.22.17

Comment: Did you get to a working deployment? the documentation on this sort of thing is a little thin on the ground...